# Tmux detaches from one side when force to adjust redimension

Tags: tmux

Whenever I have a tmux's session opened at the same time in more than one terminal with different sizes it auto adjusts its size to the smaller one. I could fix that by doing `C-b` and then `:attach -d` but it kicks the other side from the session. Is there any way to keep both sides in the session with different sizes and adjusted by its size?

Here is a picture of what it happens when I need to use `C-b` + `:attach -d`:

[image: http://oi59.tinypic.com/10z777p.jpg]

If I adjust that session and there are other terminals attached to that session they will be detached automatically and the same thing would happen if the other terminal re-attach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to keep both sides in the session with different sizes and adjusted by its size?

No.  The `stdin` of the shell you're running in tmux has a [line discipline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline).  You can see its settings with `stty -a`, and you'll notice that the (shell's idea of) terminal size is part of these settings.  Since there is a a single line discipline, you can only have a single terminal size.  Thus if you change this size, the change is reflected in all views of the session.

Comment: Can't I reuse the void space within the same tmux session? Or at least scale it to fill the  unused area?

Comment: Nope.  It's a single size, and it has to fit inside the smallest terminal.

Comment: I'm trying something like open a different tmux session split it in half and trying to attach the upper half to the smaller session, but it doesn't seems to work neither, it doesn't prompt an error but it seems to attach a different session or something.